# I am looking for a detailed list of known reductions of NP-Complete problems

Tags: np-complete, db.databases

I am looking for a detailed list of known reductions of NP-Complete problems. Much like Richard Karp's list of 21 NP-Complete problems has more than a dozen reductions, I am looking for a bigger database. Is there such a database? If not, where can I find known reductions along with citations?

Comment: There is no such database. Hundreds of NP-complete problems have been identified in hundreds of papers, and they are not maintained in any central repository. If you are interested in a particular problem, search the literature on that problem.

Comment: You might be interested in the answers to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408250/is-there-a-website-or-a-survey-collecting-all-np-complete-problems-on-graph-theo

Comment: There's Garey and Johnson's book *Computers and Intractability: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness.* This has a long list of problems at the end (pp. 187–284).